# Installing Debian on SSD

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation, dual-boot

I have an Acer laptop (Aspire E1, x64, amd i7, ram 16, vga 2). 
My base tasks are using virtual machines. 
I use dual boot for `Win10` & `Debian 8.6`. The type of BIOS boot is `Legacy`.

I am gonna change my HDD to SSD and install just `Debian 9.8` (so need at least two primary partitions).

My mainboard supports both `Legacy` and `UEFI` mode.
I know `UEFI` mode just runs on GPT not MBR.

Please consult,

Do you agree to install debian in `UEFI` mode?

If yes, is it enough to change BIOS type to `UEFI` and then start the installation? Or need more instructions?

My system specification:

```
Aspire E1-572PG - x64
BIOS Version/Date: Insyde Corp. V2.17, 02-Sep-14
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz, 2401 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Mode now: Legacy
```

Comment: I am. Debian Installation from official Debian Intaller is not an unattended process, you always need more instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 9 fully supports UEFI, but does not yet support Secure Boot, so you'll need to disable Secure Boot before running the Debian 9 installer. Unfortunately that is something you must do in the firmware settings ("BIOS settings"), and so is specific to your system's firmware implementation.

(Debian 10 apparently will support Secure Boot. Finding a way to support it in a way that would not compromise Debian's Free Software principles took a while, as an absolute requirement to rely on a binary blob that the user cannot reproduce from source at will was an anathema for Debian. A detached signature together with a reproducible build of the shim bootloader seems to be an acceptable solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Changing to UEFI and starting installation will be fine. 
UEFI is the new normal, Legacy will go away over time.

Latest releases of debian fully support UEFI

https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI